# How to include two items as a page main content in pageview -- Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, hybrid-mobile-app, flutter-pageview

Is it possible to use `PageView` to reach the following work?

I'd like to use two containers as the main content for a page in `PageView`.

I've tried to adjust `viewPortFraction` but it doesn't work as I expected.

The following effect is used by `Apple App store` and `Prime Video` and many apps.

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate more why the viewPortFraction doesn’t work as expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to use an horizontal  `ListView` with `PageScrollPhysics()` In the `physics` param.

Comment: That works for me!
But, I'm still figuring out how to make two items appear in each screen perfectly.

Comment: You have two options here for calculate the width of each item: Half Screen->MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2.
Half Size container-> User LayoutBuilder and get the parent size in constraints

Comment: We can't do onPageChanged with this though.

Answer (score 2):

You can using `viewportFraction` params in `PageController`;

Comment: this is precisely what I want, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using PageView, you could just use a ListView with

```
scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal
```

This way you could achieve the same result. You would need to somehow provide an explicit height to your ListView if I am not mistaken.

Below is a working sample.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Example'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text(
              "Top Games",
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 200,
            child: ListView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              children: <Widget>[
                GameCard(
                  "The Game 1",
                  "A puzzle game",
                  "https://lorempixel.com/200/200/abstract/",
                ),
                GameCard(
                  "The Game 2",
                  "An even beter game",
                  "https://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/2/",
                ),
                GameCard(
                  "SportMania",
                  "Editors Choice",
                  "https://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/3/",
                ),
                GameCard(
                  "MonkeySports",
                  "Monkeys playing Sport",
                  "https://lorempixel.com/200/200/abstract",
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class GameCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final String gameTitle;
  final String gameDescr;
  final String imgUrl;
  GameCard(
    this.gameTitle,
    this.gameDescr,
    this.imgUrl,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      elevation: 3,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            child: Image.network(
              imgUrl,
              width: 180,
              height: 130,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
            width: 180,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  gameTitle,
                  maxLines: 2,
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                Text(
                  gameDescr,
                  maxLines: 2,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Example]

Hope this gets you started.

Comment: Xander, 
Thanks for the demo.
I want these two items showing on one screen and want them to be able to stick with edge of screen. `PageScrollPhysics()` and `physics` are the key I was looking for.